# Python append not working for axis=1 in 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

#Python append not working for axis=1 in 2d array.

```
import numpy as np 
    
    TwoDArray = np.array([[11, 15, 10, 6], 
                          [10, 14, 11, 5],
                          [12, 17, 12, 8],
                          [15, 18, 14, 9]])
    print(TwoDArray)
    
    new2d = np.append(TwoDArray, [[1,2,3,4]], axis=1) #this line of code has the problem
    print(new2d)
```

Comment: how about axis=0?

Comment: What do you expect?  One array is (4,4), the other (1,4).  They can't be joined on axis 1.  This `np.append` is just a call to `np.concatenate` (as the full error will show you).  Reread its docs!

Comment: axis= 0 is working

Answer (score 0):

```
new2d = np.append(TwoDArray, [[1,2,3,4]], axis=0)
new2d
array([[11, 15, 10,  6],
       [10, 14, 11,  5],
       [12, 17, 12,  8],
       [15, 18, 14,  9],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4]])
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged: please consider adding comments to your code.

Comment: @csgroen, do you really think a comment will help this answer?  Or is this recommendation just a matter of form?

Comment: It's a matter of longevity of your answer - you can explain why his answer wasn't working for example (i.e. axis `0` is first dimension (rows), axis `1` is second dimension (columns)). I hadn't seen the comment above when I made this comment here, but you still can explain it here in a single sentence :)